# Check if last div and change click handler jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have 7 divs in a variable that I cycle through on a button click. Once I reach the last div, I want to change the click handler of the button.

My problem is finding the last div. I know there are ways of doing this, div.last(); etc. But my issue is that whenever I find the div that way, and check with an if statement. My changes don't work.

I have two functions:

```
function Progress() {
  //Cycle through divs
  $('#next').on('click', function() {
    i = (i + 1) % divs.length;
    divs.fadeOut().eq(i).fadeIn().addClass('transition-in');
 }
}

function SendForm() {
  //Send the form
}
```

This successfully cycles through, but continues once the end is reached. I was thinking of doing something along the lines of:

```
if(lastDiv) {
  SendForm();
}

else { 
 Progress(); 
}
```

Of course I tried that, and it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this..

```
function Progress() {
  //Cycle through divs
  $('#next').on('click', function() {
    i = (i + 1) % divs.length;
    if(i == divs.length){
      sendForm();
    }else{
      divs.fadeOut().eq(i).fadeIn().addClass('transition-in');
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing happened when I did this. Do you think it would have anything to do with the divs.length value being 7 and i increments from 0?

Comment: Probably.. It was just a general idea. It's untested

Comment: Yeah, I tested it and that was the issue. I've solved the problem now using a different method, thanks for your help.

Comment: Replace `if(i == divs.length){` with `if(i === (divs.length-1)){` (you are using modulo arithmetics).